# Python Plotly: AttributeError: 'PlotlyJSONEncoder' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Tags: python, plotly

I am getting an error when trying to plot the basic chart on the Plotly Tutorial: https://plot.ly/python/getting-started/.

Full traceback here:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File "testing_plotly.py", line 13, in  unique_url =
>   py.plot(data, filename = 'basic-line')
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line
>   186, in plot res = _send_to_plotly(figure, **plot_options)
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line
>   1229, in _se cls=utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\json__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
>   **kw).encode(obj)
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\json\encoder.py", line 192, in encode chunks =
>   self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
>
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\plotly\utils.py", line 151, in
>   iterencode if self.encoding != 'utf-8': AttributeError:
>   'PlotlyJSONEncoder' object has no attribute 'encoding'

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Full disclosure, I work for Plotly.

### TL;DR

Looks like a recent change isn't fully compatible with your Python version.

```
pip install -I 'plotly==1.6.10'
```

That's just before the change that seems to be affecting you.

### Explanation

The Plotly python module recently just updated our custom `JSONEncoder` subclass to convert `float('NaN')`, `float('Inf')`, and `float('-Inf')` to `null` instead to to the extended JSON values `nan`, `Infinity`, and `-Infinity`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#infinite-and-nan-number-values

To do this we overrode `iterencode` from the default `JSONEncoder`. Something may have changed between the version of this we develop on and your version.

### Permanent Fix

We'll try and recreate the error and come up with a fix shortly, thanks for posting about it!

(edit, there should have been two `=` signs in the `pip` command)

Comment: Thanks! So as of right now, with my version of Python, there's nothing that can be done until the bug is fixed, correct?

Comment: Sorry. I figured it out, I had to use:
pip install -I plotly==1.6.10

Comment: This issue should be fixed as of plotly version 1.6.12