# Pandas Dataframe to plotly plot showing TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook, plotly

I wrote a script which uses nltk's `FreqDist` module then converts it into a pandas dataframe. The code snippet is as follows:

```
    .......
    import unicodedata
    str2 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', str1).encode('ascii','ignore')    
    words = nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize(str2)

    fdist = nltk.FreqDist(words)
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(fdist, orient='index').reset_index()
    df = df.rename(columns={'index':'query_word', 0:'count'})
    df2 = df.sort_values(['count'], ascending=[False])
```

Now, I am trying to plot it using `plotly` for which my code snippet looks as follows:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go

data = [go.Bar(x= df.query_word, y= df.count)]
py.iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')
```

When I run this part, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-87d0c9af254b> in <module>()
----> 1 py.iplot(data, filename='basic-bar')

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.pyc in iplot(figure_or_data, **plot_options)
    150     if 'auto_open' not in plot_options:
    151         plot_options['auto_open'] = False
--> 152     url = plot(figure_or_data, **plot_options)
    153 
    154     if isinstance(figure_or_data, dict):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.pyc in plot(figure_or_data, validate, **plot_options)
    239 
    240     plot_options = _plot_option_logic(plot_options)
--> 241     res = _send_to_plotly(figure, **plot_options)
    242 
    243     if res['error'] == '':

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/plotly/plotly.pyc in _send_to_plotly(figure, **plot_options)
   1407     fig = tools._replace_newline(figure)  # does not mutate figure
   1408     data = json.dumps(fig['data'] if 'data' in fig else [],
-> 1409                       cls=utils.PlotlyJSONEncoder)
   1410     credentials = get_credentials()
   1411     validate_credentials(credentials)

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.pyc in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, encoding, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    249         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
    250         separators=separators, encoding=encoding, default=default,
--> 251         sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
    252 
    253 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/utils.pyc in encode(self, o)
    144 
    145         # this will raise errors in a normal-expected way
--> 146         encoded_o = super(PlotlyJSONEncoder, self).encode(o)
    147 
    148         # now:

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.pyc in encode(self, o)
    205         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    206         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 207         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    208         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    209             chunks = list(chunks)

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.pyc in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    268                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    269                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 270         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    271 
    272 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/utils.pyc in default(self, obj)
    211             except NotEncodable:
    212                 pass
--> 213         return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
    214 
    215     @staticmethod

/usr/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.pyc in default(self, o)
    182 
    183         """
--> 184         raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
    185 
    186     def encode(self, o):

TypeError: <bound method DataFrame.count of                     query_word  count
0                          1,2      1
1                         four      1
2                       prefix      1
..                      ......      ..
..                      ......      ..
3                    francesco      1
```

As far as I understand from the other SF questions on the topic "*is not json serializable*" and from the error message, it is the problem with encoding? and not of the datatype.

Because, when I `print type(df2.query_word)` it says `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`. So how to make a series serializable? Since the traceback doesn't show any encoding error such as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022989/python-plotly-attributeerror-plotlyjsonencoder-object-has-no-attribute-enco) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38640800/unicodedecodeerror-error-when-displaying-dataframe-on-ipython-notebook).

What is the easy turn-around? My main intension to post this question is to understand whether this is a problem with dataframe, the data, ipython or plotly.

Comment: My guess is that, since `numpy.float64` is not serializable by the standard json module, the call to `json.dumps` fails. The usual workaround is to call the `to_json` method in pandas, but here it happens inside the plotly function you call. Can you try to pass the data in a different format, not as a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @IanS You mean, I can simply convert using ```df[column_name].tolist() ?```

Comment: I don't know what formats `iplot` accepts, but something like that, yes. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11389998/5276797) to convert to native Python types accepted by json.